# How to run DotNet Core applications in Azure Batch Jobs

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-batch

I have followed [Azure Batch ffmpeg tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/batch-dotnet-ffmpeg-tutorial/) and it works as expected. The problem that I have at this point is that my executable that i want to run as a batch is a dotnet core application and images that are available when creating a Pool do not have dot net core installed. In the task command line I need to run something like `dotnet myApp.dll myParam` but *dotnet* is not available.

How do I go about having an image that has dotnet core installed. Do I need to create a custom image? Is there a tutorial for doing that. I tried using Docker with [dotnetcore runtime image](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-core-runtime/) at some point for running the same application locally and that seems to work. Do I need to export this image to Azure somehow? Or can I push the core installation into an image in another way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am understanding your issue correctly, the simplest solution I see would be create your own custom image to provision a batch pool. We have a document on achieving that here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-custom-images

This way you can preconfigure an image that has all the needed programs and languages installed right away.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So creating a custom image will require to do it on a VM (and take a snapshot), instead of a Docker. I will give it a try.

Comment: Yes correct :) But it is as simple as that. And it should really save you time in the long run as well not having to install anything. If you hit any snags just let me know.

Comment: I think new self contained deployment option will eliminate the need for installing .net core runtime https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#publish-self-contained